# PEM file (export certificate - trusted in Postman)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, postman, pem, certificate-authority

I need to create a PEM file of a SSL (CA) certificate. Chrome does provide an option to view the certficate and export it as *Base64 encoded X.509 (*.CER)* file. In addition, the file extension can be changed to .PEM. Does the certificate only contain public information and can it safely be shared with other people (let's say colleagues)?
E.g. Stackoverflow contains a Root CA certificate. If I create the PEM file and share it with somebody, does it even matter or is there any security risk?

Background info: I need to export the SSL certificate (as .PEM) from an API endpoint in order to add it as trusted CA certificate in Postman.

Comment: Yes what Chrome/Windows (also IE) calls 'base64 X.509' is what everybody else calls PEM. Yes certificates (including X.509) are designed to be public, especially roots. Also, SO (following recommended practice) does not send any root cert, but rather a LetsEncrypt intermediate cert that _points to_ a root (currently still DST X3, not updated to ISRG X1 as LE now recommends). When your browser shows this chain including a root, that root is coming from the truststore local to the browser (Firefox) or OS (Chrome, IE, Safari).

Comment: FY(: Although the big blob of base64 is the most obvious thing to a person in any PEM file, PEM is not _just_ base64; it is base64 (usually of DER) _with line breaks and header and footer_. Windows (Microsoft) as usual doesn't care about being accurate or fully conforming to standards.